# HTML Fields in Edit Mode Help

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, page-layout, html, snippet

So this is what I have done, I have created a menu on one of my SharePoint pages using a custom html list and CSS to make it look nice. I have then taken that HTML file and converted it into a master page and page layout.

Example of what I have created
[image]

I was wondering if it was possible to set up SharePoint so that when you go into the editing mode you will be able to edit the values of the menu items directly instead of going into the HTML code and changing them.

Comment: I think this is not possible. You will always have to go into the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you store the labels in a List or somewhere and whack on a huge amount of JavaScript to write a CMS yourself.

You might be better of thinking the SP way:

- Store your List metadata in a SharePoint List
- Use Display Templates or Client Side Rendering ( use [Cisar](https://365csi.nl/cisar) ! )

To create the HTML content

That is what the standard Promoted Links WebPart does for you